# ASP.NET MVC 4 - using views/models from different namespace/project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

VS 2012
MVC 4

Any recommendations on the best approach for the following?

I want to be able to:
Call views and use models in namespace A 
from controllers in namespace B and C, but use the layouts/images from namespace B and C.

I've looked at the MasterName view property, but that didn't seem to be a good solutions as to what I'm trying to accomplish, because the layouts are in the A and B namespaces.

namespace: A
    Models
    Views

website: B
namespace: B
    layout: B
    images: B
    controller: B

website: C
namespace: C
    layout: C
    images: C
    controller: C

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having? There is no restriction that prevents this type of arrangement.  Can you show some code that isn't working or compiling?

Comment: Your solution structure is atypical, and probably not optimal. You should not have two website projects in a solution. In your single website project, you should define Namespace `A` have all the appropriate website artefacts: Views, layouts, controllers, images. You could then have a separate class library for your models where you would define Namespace `B`. For other projects layers (data access, services, etc...) you could create separate projects where you would define additional namespaces.